# Need help to buy a computer for VM, i7 vs E5-2660 V1

Tags: desktop

I want to buy a computer where i can run more than 3 Hyper-V at a time. One choice I have is to buy some new core i7 it will cost me around US$800/1000

Usage of Hyper-V

1. Windows Server 2012 with ADFS services
2. Windows Server 2012 Sharepoint 2013/16
3. Windows Server 2012 MS SQL Server 2012
4. Windows Server 2012 ASP.Net Application (Optional)
5. Windows 10 As workstation (could be 2)

But an alternate option is to buy used HP Z620 Workstation at same price US$800/1000 (not sure these are 2012/13 models)

It has two E5-2660 2.2GHz V1 processors installed (total 16 core) 64 GB ECC Ram

I'm at point where i could not understand which system can give better performance, I did not mention details about i7 as i will go for whatever standard PC is available as new workstation is out of budget.

Thanks.

Comment: It depends on what you are wanting to run on the VMs. You can have a simple static website running on Linux for around a GB or two. Or you could run an enterprise server requiring 128GB of RAM. We need to know what this will be used for so we can give you the best recommendations.

Comment: @Cfinley I updated info regarding VM usage, please let me know if its enough information, regarding core i7 I can't be specific, but in general within budget. Thanks

Comment: Depends on the amount of cores allocated to each VM - the general advice is to have no more then two times host cores assigned to VMs or you run into scheduling issues.

Comment: I also want to learn how effective is the processor difference, like for E5 type i will have two processors (but little old models) for i7 newser but single processor, not sure which one of these is more capable, thanks

Comment: If we just talk about processing, can we say that E5 machine is more capable? as it has 16 cores, 64 GB ram (as compare to i7 with 16/32 gb ram), but obvoiusly it has down side, its has bit old processor, not sure how much proformance would be different. thanks

Comment: One of the biggest differences between Xeon series and consumer i7 series processors is going to be the RAM cap. You can obtain those by looking up the spec sheets for the individual processors as Intel is quite good with it's cpu technical specification documentation. In addition if you want to quantitatively compare CPU's head-to-head, it is generally a good idea to [compare their benchmarks. Here the i7-6700 K handed-ly defeats the E5-2660 even in multi-core scenarios](http://cpu.userbenchmark.com/Compare/Intel-Xeon-E5-2660-v2-vs-Intel-Core-i7-6700K/m13068vs3502).